# What is the default font in latex beamer?

Tags: fonts, beamer

What is the default font in LaTeX beamer. I want to use it in an ooffice master layout.

Answer (score 28):

Just compile a minimal document to PDF and check the fonts in the document properties in your PDF viewer.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    Hello World 
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

My viewer tell me that it's Computer Modern (CM) sans serif at 10pt size.

Comment: Oops! Dunno how easy *that*'s going to be to get into OO...

Comment: @Brent: Should be quite easy. Just download them [here](http://cm-unicode.sourceforge.net/download.html) or [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/) in otf (or ttf) format and install on your system like any other font.

Comment: @Caramdir: Oh! I haven't used CM for some time now; I only remember using it "the old-fashioned way" via metafont.

Comment: This question is old so I don't know if things have changed, but it seams that beamer default font is Latin Modern Sans.

Comment: I also got CM sans on the document you've compiled. However, in my case, many elements were *Latin Modern (LM)* sans. Probably due to the theme I am using. Thanks anyway for the quick and effective tip, my presentation looks much better now!

Comment: I'm confused ... The link you sent contains lots of different fonts each with name of the form (cm...). Which one of these is CM sans serif?

Comment: Never mind, by comparison it was "cmunss.otf"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pdffonts` of `poppler-utils` on the created *.pdf document and get the font information.

I compiled a dummy latex beamer slide using `pdflatex`:

```
> $ pdffonts test.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
QEVVJR+CMSS12                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no      38  0
```

and here, using `xelatex`:

```
> $ pdffonts test.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
ZHLXEF+LMSans8-Regular-Identity-H    CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      7  0
AQIKNF+LMSans12-Regular-Identity-H   CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     30  0
```

Using `xelatex` the font is `Latin Modern`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Was `titleslide.pdf` created with `beamer`?

Comment: yes, Mico, `titleslide.pdf` was created with `beamer` (not using default themes, however)

Comment: The OP's question was, "What is the default font in LaTeX `beamer`?" Your answer appears to be addressing a different question, *viz.*, "How do I find out which fonts are used in a given pdf file produced by `beamer`?"

Comment: You're right. I updated my answer compiling a minimal default beamer slide with pdflatex and xelatex and I'm showing the outputs. For xelatex, the standard font seems to be Latin Modern.